# What should the "Elevator Pitch" for this site be like?

Tags: discussion, site-topic, beta, promotion

**The Elevator Pitch**:

`You just stepped onto an elevator with a group of strangers.  Before the elevator gets to the next floor, your challenge is to describe and "sell" the Project Management Stack Exchange site before the elevator reaches the next floor.  What will you say?`

When trying to recruit more users on this site, what do we say -- in one sentence -- to describe the purpose of the site to non-StackExchange users?

- What is a tagline that should describe the site?
- StackOverflow, Serverfault, and Superuser all have their own unique domain names:

  http://stackoverflow.com
  http://serverfault.com
  http://superuser.com

  Is there a specific domain name that should be used for this site, other than `pm.stackexchange.com` or a subdomain of http://stackexchange.com?  What are some good suggestions that could help make the site stand out?
- What is the website's motto?

Comment: Focusing on [domains names is the wrong approach](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/).  In the [4th essential question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), please note that domain names are heavily de-emphasized.

Comment: @Rebecca - I did see that, but I thought that maybe if we have a really great idea for a domain name we can use it.  However, I don't want to push for something like this without more support and unity from other users.  Naming is tough, but what makes it tougher is also finding a name everyone is passionate about.

Comment: it just seemed like a significant amount of the focus of the responses/comments were domain-based.  Tell us what your site is about first. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this question, here is what we ended up coming up with in the [FAQ](https://pm.stackexchange.com/faq):

> ***Project Management - Stack Exchange is for expert and enthusiast project managers who have questions about managing projects.***

However, this isn't set in stone. As we learn more about the challenges of the site, we may want to re-evaluate not only the elevator pitch but also other information in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

A community forum about projects and project management.

Comment: are you sure that this is a "forum"? The idea of the entire SO/SE stack of sites is to be a Q&A database, not a discussion forum. At least, this is my feeling..

Comment: @yegor256, I know where you're coming from. Its hard to describe the SO/SE approach to someone who is not familiar with it. It is a Q&A database but does have a large community and discussion component to it.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow and Server Fault both have their names derived from when something actually goes wrong in that specific area of expertise. Makes sense, if you consider that that's when you're likely to have questions to ask. Could we not go down that path?

I don't know what's a snappy PM counterpart, though... ProjectOverdue?

Tagline: Because entropy always increases

... shit, I'm terrible at this, but you get the general idea.

Comment: I like the way you think.  The Domain Name does match the pattern, and it's available!  +1

Comment: Strikes me as being too technical. Plus project management is more than just late tasks. Its more about management.

Comment: @Mark: I'm not very fond of my own examples either, but I would like to see more examples in that vein (i.e. names derived from things that can go wrong in project management). Development is not just about resolving stack overflow errors. I don't think that the domain name has to be all-encompassing for the site, but it should strike at the heart of it, and that I'm not sure my suggestion does.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some of my ideas:

Tagline: ask, answer & sharing - all about project discussion

Proposed domain name: project.stackexchange.com . I think it's clearer than pm (kind of messaging)

Motto: a community that is built on individual industry experience; a place that people can ask, get helped and share their own story.

Comment: I agree @ `project.stackexchange.com` honestly. "pm.SE" just sounds like some sort of messaging system. I also like the Tagline. Not sure about the motto.

Comment: Look at http://superuser.com and http://serverfault.com.  Those sites have their own second-level domain, not a subdomain of stackexchange.com.  What about http://projectify.com?  It's available.

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  Looks like someone bought it but isn't using it... lame.  How about http://projectmanageable.com.  Probably too many syllables, but maybe it gives someone else some good ideas!

Comment: I like something less technical and more to the point e.g. projectmanagement.se.com  or management.se.com.

Answer (score 2):

How about this: "project management experts answer your questions"

Answer (score 0):

I generally tell people

> "it's a project management Q&A site
>   containing questions covering any
>   aspect or project management.  Any
>   industry is fair game."

I like the [general idea David Hedlund was moving towards](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-should-the-elevator-pitch-for-this-site-be-like/38#38) - taking a negative and turning it into a positive.

How about silverbullet.stackexchange.com? Sadly, SilverBullet.com is already taken. nosilverbullets.com is available, though.

Going totally gloom & doom, we could go for ProjectDeathMarch.com ;-)