# Can the Administrators of This Site Award one of the Following Domain Names to the Site?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, beta

Some of us have discussed domain names for this site.  [David Hedlund proposed the domain name `projectoverdue.com`](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-should-the-elevator-pitch-for-this-site-be-like/38#38) to match the same noun-adjective pattern used for `serverfault.com` and  `stackoverflow.com`.

The domain name is available for $11.99 and would make a great name for this site.  I believe it will also help make it stand out.

**Who do I talk to who has the power to make this happen?**

[ProjectOverdue on GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/domains/searchresults2.aspx?ci=16811)

Comment: Sites generally don't get a domain name until they get out of beta (except for AskUbuntu), furthermore the team is rather hesitant to pick a name just like that, it's not like you can change it that easily after a year

Comment: @Ivo - Why don't you put that as your answer?

Comment: There you go @jmort :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the up-and-coming Stack Exchange sites will be sticking with their topic.stackexchange.com. Some of the older sites have legacy names but whenever possible, we are sticking with the Stack Exchange subdomain.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

Comment: According to the blog post that you have linked at the top of this site, [7 Essential Questions for Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), domain names are included as part of your suggested [Elevator Pitch](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-should-the-elevator-pitch-for-this-site-be-like) question.  Since the Oct blog post supersedes the July blog post, could you perhaps link them together?  The 7 Essential Questions is hard coded at the top and caused me confusion because it didn't include recent updates.

Comment: I ran out of room.  I wanted to clarify that I was pushing on the domain name issue because I thought it was encouraged.  After looking at your most recent blog post, I can understand what makes this such a painful process, and I understand the challenges.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Sites generally don't get a domain name until they get out of beta (except for AskUbuntu).

Furthermore the team is rather hesitant to pick a name just like that, because changing the domain name after a year would be a pretty dramatic change. True, changing it from pm.SE to something else is too, but at least pm.SE is pretty generic.

Answer (score 0):

The original name for this site, which is actually still functioning, is [askaboutprojects.com](http://www.askaboutprojects.com)

Comment: Is this really true?  I looked at Ask About Projects, and it does not look to be a part of the Stack Exchange network?  I assumed someone was just trying to cheaply copy StackExchange.  Where can I find more information on this site and why it's not part of the network?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi jmort253. AskAboutProjects.com was created on Stackexchange, but it had to go through the proposal-phase on Area51. And this site is the result. The Admin of AskAboutProjects, Tucson (http://askaboutprojects.com/users/2/tucson), is the one who set up the proposal here. Maybe you can contact him through the "Contact us by e-mail" link on AskAboutProjects.com

Comment: Thanks.  I was just curious about how it related to StackExchange as well as why my SE accounts aren't associated with AskAboutProjects.  There are 0 links to anything related to SE there.